# Silent mapping that automatically redraws -- no messages or blank screen

Tags: vimrc

I would like to open a url in vim. Using `gx` from netrw has been problematic, so I created the following simple mapping:

```
nnoremap <leader>k !open <C-R><C-F><CR>
```

This gets the filepath under the cursor and then executes it, with the command looking like:

```
:!open http://google.com
```

However, I hate that whenever I open a file (or url) it prompts me with:

```
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

So then I enter in `silent` at the start:

```
:silent !open http://google.com
```

And it opens without that message, but when I go back to it the screen is blank, which is equally annoying.

Is there a way to just "open the link normally"? I.e., not the prompt me with a message, make the screen go blank, or anything other than opening the file/url on its own? How can I do this?

Comment: Please [edit] and move your answer into an answer

Comment: @D.BenKnoble thanks, updated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this you can prepend `silent` to the command. For example, the following will work:

```
nnoremap <leader>k :execute 'silent !open <C-R><C-F>' \| redraw!<CR>
```

Note also the need to escape the `|` in the mapping to force redraw at the end as well.

Comment: David, you can accept your own answer.