# What is :silent !echo doing? Why does it get the cursor to the top?

Tags: external-command, shell

[This question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64268666/insane-vim-shell-cursor-command) triggered my curiosity.

What does `:silent !echo` doing?

The first time I saw something like `:excommand !shellcommand` was when I was looking for a way to save a read-only file from within a non-`sudo` Vim session. Indeed I found the famous [How does the vim “write with sudo” trick work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600783/how-does-the-vim-write-with-sudo-trick-work). In that case, however, it's "easy" to search for `:help :w` and scroll down a bit find the entry `:[range]w[rite] [++opt] !{cmd}` which describes the meaning of that  `!`.

In the case of `:silent`, instead, doing `:help :silent` doesn't bring anywhere the question mark is used after a space and before `{command}`.

My understanding is that `:silent !echo` is working mostly like `:!echo` but without showing any of the output or of the underlying shell, ***and*** sending the cursor to the top of the screen. I've recorded a screencast for reference. (NOTE: All those horizontal lines that you see happen to be present only in the screencast, for some reason, there's no such a thing in my system.)

[This question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/26011/silent-mapping-that-automatically-redraws-no-messages-or-blank-screen) seems related.

[image: asciicast]

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's `:silent`:

```
:sil[ent][!] {command}  Execute {command} silently.  Normal messages will not
                        be given or added to the message history.
```

and there's `:!`

```
:!{cmd}         Execute {cmd} with the shell.  See also the 'shell'
                and 'shelltype' option.
```

Your hunch is mostly correct; I'm not sure why the cursor goes to the top of the screen, but it's probably because the command outputs a drawing code (termcap stuff), which vim is also using to draw on the screen.